# Rails defining methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods

I would like to define a method where the first argument is required and the rest are optional. Only first argument must be at first pace.

I try to do this:

```
my_method(:id, :tags, :user)
my_method(:id, :user, :tags)

def(id, *args)
 ... id...
 ... args[:tags]...
 ... args[:user]...
end
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. I used this code:

```
def(id, options={})
end
```